# Nested state URL is incorrect with angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My routes look like

```
$stateProvider.state("k8math", {
  abstract: true,
  url: "/k8math",
  templateUrl: "/views/k8math.html"
}).state("k8math.questions", {
  url: "questions",
  templateUrl: "/views/k8math/questions.html"
});
```

When I have a link like:
`<li ng-hide="showLogin"><a ui-sref="k8math.questions">K-8 Math</a></li>` it goes to `http://localhost:3000/k8mathquestions` instead of `http://localhost:3000/k8math/questions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a leading slash in your url :

```
.state("k8math.questions", {
  url: "/questions",
  templateUrl: "/views/k8math/questions.html"
});
```

The url of nested states are relatives, but doesn't include the leading slash [(example in docs)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#appended-routes-default)